# Firebase two projects one database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I have two separate web projects that use one firebase DB.

*Project A :*

- Cloud Firestore
- Storage
- Auth
- Hosting

**Configuration**:

apiKey: 'ABC',

databaseURL: 'https://ABC.firebaseio.com',

projectId: 'ABC-eee47'

*Project B:*

- Hosting

**Configuration**:

apiKey: 'ABC',

databaseURL: 'https://ABC.firebaseio.com',

projectId: 'DFG-eee47'

Project A works perfectly, problem is in project B that should use project's A database. Requests to database from project B are denied if projectId is not the same as in project A. But I need the Ids to be different as I have auto deploy to hosting.

Comment: You can just use the configuration for Project A in your JS and deploy it to Project B. The only thing you can't do is attach a rewrite from Project B to a function in Project A.

Comment: What do your security rules look like on the database?

Comment: @DougStevenson "Anyone with your database reference will be able to read or write to your database" so all open :(

Comment: @MichaelBleigh maybe you are right, I can use "firebase use <alias_or_project_id>" in CI/CD

Comment: Others will only be able to read and write your database if security rules allow it.  Users from other projects won't be able to.